# Searching copyright records

Tags: copyright

In US copyright office how can closed or withdrawn cases be looked at? I tried the search on their website but it gives only registered results if i am not wrong. Well what about closed and withdrawn applications?

And do they publish accepted or other closed registrations when they are finalized? Where? I couldn't see it either.

Comment: https://www.copyright.gov/help/

Comment: Can you link to the website.  This might be a policy thing that does not post applications that were rejected or withdrawn (I'm not sure close is the right term... typically closing an application means the application was resolved either in acceptance or rejection and is no longer moving through the application system.  It's likely only available for internal tracking only.).

Would also help if you explained your purpose in looking for the rejected or withdrawn applications.

Comment: When I looked at their research link on their site i only saw approved ones. Just was curious if they are the only ones displayed publicly or i missed something. Because I believed once a case is closed, either positive or negative or no decision it is available for viewing. I also wanted to know for the future when I applyfor something and what if i withdraw it or it gets closed without approval..